How can i read only a decimal number with decimal point in a line including another dots in bash script?
I want to read only a decimal number with decimal point in a line including another dots in bash script. I want to read a decimal number from a line such as

SIMULATION BOX VOLUME......................................:    6250.000000

In the end, I want to get the decimal number

6250.000000

How can I eliminate words, dots, : , and spaces before the decimal number by using the '''sed''' command?
Thank You in Advance.

Is there a space or a tab before 6250.000000?

We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Hello Cyrus, There is no tab, only a space

This might help: bash, text file remove all text in each line before the last space
